# Doubts will object registered in IAppBuilder.CreatePerOwinContext() be disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, dynamics-crm-365

i have some doubts will my object be disposed.

I customized Owin flow becauze we use CRM as database and administration, so i registered `OrganizationServiceProxy` in `CreatePerOwinContext()`

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(CrmConnection.Create);
```

inherited class from `OrganizationServiceProxy`

```
public class CrmConnection : OrganizationServiceProxy
{
    private CrmConnection() 
        : base(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrmUri"])
                , null
                , new ClientCredentials()
                    {
                        UserName =
                        {
                            UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrmUsername"],
                            Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CrmPassword"]
                        }
                    }
                , null
              )
    { }

    public static CrmConnection Create()
    {
        return new CrmConnection();
    }
```

So my doubts are will instance of this object be disposed after request is over?

I did some research and if i got it right every object passed to `CreatePerOwinContext()` should be of type IDisposable?

Comment: Since it's of type `IDisposable` you should be able to implement the `Dispose` method and do all the disposing you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> every object passed to CreatePerOwinContext() should be of type
>   IDisposable?

More than *should* be. Has to Be. Look at the signature of `CreatePerOwinContext`

```
public static IAppBuilder CreatePerOwinContext<T>(
    this IAppBuilder app,
    Func<IdentityFactoryOptions<T>, IOwinContext, T> createCallback
)
where T : class, IDisposable
```

You can't register anything that doesn't implement `IDisposable`

> So my doubts are will instance of this object be disposed after
>   request is over?

You can verify this by logging calls to `Dispose`

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    base.Dispose(disposing);
    Debug.WriteLine($"I'm disposing");
}
```

Comment: Thx, atm i can't try but i will try tommorow and get back with info.

Comment: Here i am, it does call overridden `Dispose()`.I added little flavor and registered few callback function that return new `CrmConnection` and `Dispose()` was called exact number of times i registered callback functions. Thx for helping :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Shoe's logging method, you can verify disposal by creating a `WeakReference` to your object, waiting for the request to complete, manually calling the garbage collector, then checking `WeakReference.Target`.  As long as nothing else is holding a reference, `Target` will return `null` if the object has been collected.

The `WeakReference` will allow you to hold a reference to an instance of something, but will still allow it to be garbage collected.

Don't do this in production code of course, this is just to proove to yourself that the object was disposed.

The handy thing about this method, is that it will work for any object, even ones that are outside your control where you can't override `IDisposable`.

```
var reference = new WeakReference(myIDsiposableInstance, true);

//Make a request, and wait for it to complete

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

if(reference.Target == null)
{
    //Disposed
}
else
{
    //Not Disposed
}
```

Comment: I am not sure where should i put this `WeakReference` ? Should i put it in that overriden `Dispose(bool ..)` method?

Comment: You would want to put it close to where you instantiate the object it is going to have a reference to.  It also has to have a large enough scope to be visible when you are ready to check its `Target` property.

Comment: Week reference still have reference on that instance or i didn't do it right. I did it like this, i made `WeakReference` as static variable because function that retrieve new `CrmConnection` instance need to be static, last function that is called in Owin flow is `Dispose()` that i override and i check week reference in that `Dispose()` method.

Comment: Did you call the 2 methods on `GC`? You need those to force the garbage collector to run. Call them immediately before checking the reference.

Comment: I called both methods `GC.Collect();` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` and nothing hapens. Maybe because `IAppBuilder` still holds reference to instance.

Answer (score 1):

`OrganizationServiceProxy` derives from `ServiceProxy<TService>` which implements `IDisposable`. If neither the derived nor abstract classes implemented `IDisposable` then it wouldn't be valid as a return value for the `Func<T>` passed to `CreatePerOwinContext` (as there is a constraint on `T` requiring it to implement `IDisposable`.) This would lead to a compiler error.

The only reasons to worry it isn't being disposed is because you believe there is a bug in the implementation of OWIN that isn't calling the `Dispose` method or that there is a bug in either `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy` or `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy<TService>` that is not allowing the object to be disposed.

Comment: Is there certain way to determine that OrganizationServiceProxy connection has been closed?